# Assigning value in a const

Tags: javascript, reactjs, constants

How do I assign a value in my const?

In the form I have some input from checked and when the value is true, I need to change this value to communicate with the client's webservice and if it is false, I need to change the value too, but I can not do this simply by declaring const with the new value .

I tried to change the value directly in const, but it does not work

Follow my code in CodeSandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/n08n2m7mpj

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import Switch from "@material-ui/core/Switch";

import "./styles.css";

function App(props) {
  const initialFormState = {
    datRev: "01/05/2019",
    empRev: "1",
    numCad: "5",
    numEmp: "1",
    obsRev: "ReactJS done!",
    sitRev: "1",
    tipCol: "1",
    tipEqp: "10",
    tipSvc: "100",
    cheklist: {
      "": "",
      "": "",
      "": "",
      "": ""
    },

    codCkl: "4",
    sitCkl: "N",
    selPro: "S",
    obsCkl: "obs insomina"
  };

  const [equipRev, setEquipRevisao] = useState(initialFormState);
  const [checkedA, setCheckedA] = useState(false);

  const handleChange = nameChecked => event => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;

    setCheckedA({ [nameChecked]: event.target.checked });

    if (event.target.checked === true) {
      console.log("True: " + event.target.checked);
      const value = "S";
    } else {
      console.log("False: " + event.target.checked);
      const value = "N";
    }

    console.log("Value: " + value);
    setEquipRevisao({ ...equipRev, [name]: value });

    console.log("sitCkl: " + equipRev.sitCkl);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>

      <Switch
        name="sitCkl"
        checked={props.checkedA}
        onChange={handleChange("checkedA")}
        value={equipRev.sitCkl}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

I hope that the "event.target.checked" is true, it changes the value of the sitCkl from equipRev to 'S' and when it is false, it changes the value of sitCkl from equipRev to 'N'.

Comment: So don't declare it as constant, declare it as variable. `const` means `it will never change`

Comment: The idea of `const` is to prevent the identifier from binding to a new value. If you will need to change the value, you should declare the identifier with `let` (or `var`).

Comment: `const` is almost `immutable`. Use `let` instead of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have to change its value, then you can declare it with `let` instead of `const`. (The whole point of `const` is not reassigning value).

```
  const handleChange = nameChecked => event => {
    let { name, value } = event.target;

    setCheckedA({ [nameChecked]: event.target.checked });

    if (event.target.checked === true) {
      console.log("True: " + event.target.checked);
      value = "S";
//...
```

Answer (score 0):

> Constants are block-scoped, much like variables defined using the let
>   statement. The value of a constant cannot change through reassignment,
>   and it can't be redeclared

So the point of a const is that once it is declared, it can't be changed. If you need the ability to assign and reassign a value to a variable. You will be better using **let** or **var**.